# Program scans only one line of input instead of all of them

Tags: c

I have a assignment where I need to  write a program that reads the text file input.txt line by line. Edits these lines and writes them to the text file output.txt as follows:

-in-odd lines override numbers -inear lines overwrite letters (a-z, A-Z) with a hyphen.

All is fine aside from that the program itself only reads first line from input.txt and puts only that one line changed into output.txt
What did I do wrong ?

```
int cv6_treti()
{
   char riadok[1000];
   int x=1, y;
   FILE *fr = fopen ("vstup.txt","r");
   FILE *fw = fopen ("vystup.txt","w");
   fscanf (fr, "%s",riadok);

    while (y < 1000){

    if (x%2==1){
            if (riadok[y] >= '0' && riadok[y] <= '9'){
                riadok[y] = '*';
            }
    }

    else if (x%2==0) {
        if (riadok [y]>= 'a' && riadok[y] <= 'z'){
            riadok[y] = '-';
        }
        if (riadok [y]>= 'A' && riadok[y] <= 'Z'){
            riadok[y] = '-';
        }
    }
    y++;

}
    fprintf (fw, "%s",riadok);
    fclose(fw);
    fclose(fr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think  ```FILE fw = fopen ("vystup.txt","w");``` here ```fw``` must be a ```FILE * fw```.

Comment: You only read a single line from file. If you want to read more than one, you must either write more `fscanf`s or put one in a loop.

Comment: Doctor Gonzo, what do you think is the value of `y` the first time `while (y < 1000){` executes?

Comment: The value of `x` doesn't change.

Comment: I am not sure @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Doctor Gonzo, what value of `y` did you want the first time `while (y < 1000){` executes?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's there so it goes up to 1000 characters max

Comment: @DoctorGonzo Yes, nice to report why you want it, but what _value_ did you want `y` to start with in `while (y < 1000){`?  Did you want it to start with 0, 1, 42, or ...?  With `int x=1, y;`, `y` is not initialized/assigned with anything yet.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica so I just add 0 to it ? because it still only scans first line

Comment: @DoctorGonzo 1) Rather than "just add 0 to it" (adding 0 to an indeterminate `y` with `y = y + 0;`), initialize it to 0 just like code did for `x`.  `int y = 0;`.   2) " because it still only scans first line" --> of course.  Code only reads one word of input with `fscanf (fr, "%s",riadok);`.  If you want to read multiple lines, call `fgets()` multiple times.  Other problems exist too.  Good luck -GTG.

Comment: @DoctorGonzo -- did you solve your problem? If not, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (and a few lines of sample input from the file) Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: the posted code is missing a `main()` function, so will not link.  the posted code is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header file: `#include <stdio.h>` so will not compile.

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fr = fopen ("vstup.txt","r");` and 'FILE *fw = fopen ("vystup.txt","w");`  Always check the returned value (fr and fw) are not NULL to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `fscanf (fr, "%s",riadok);`  the `%s` input format conversion specifier will stop as soon as any white space is encountered, (like at the end of the first word in the file)  Suggest using: `fgets( buffer. sizeof( buffer), fr );` to input a whole line (assuming the buffer is big enough to hold the whole line)

Comment: when done processing a line of input, must loop back to input the next line